# Mixing Microsoft MVC ajax and validation helpers with native jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation, mixing

**Introduction**

This post is about mixing Microsoft MVC helpers with native jquery ajax. The main problems i encountered along the way were:

1. Double post submissions
2. @Html.ValidationMessageFor not outputting
   attributes

**Requirements**

1. I have a requirement to validate and post a form (id = "my-form")
2. The form is bound to a model decorated with validation attributes so I want to make use of helper methods such as @Html.ValidationMessageFor to harness unobtrusive benefits
3. I need both client side and server side validation (server side i do a unique name check with the database)
4. I need to do some client side processing when submitting the form to add additional form data.

**Iterative Steps**

**STEP 1**

I started off with no native jquery and used a Microsoft helper to create the ajax form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm( ...
```

All worked as advertised. This gave me unobtrusive validation but it did not fulfil my customised form data posting requirement.

So I thought I'd override the submit process.

**STEP 2**

In my document ready i hook up the new event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    // Rebind validators
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#my-form');

    // Hook up submit event
    $("#my-form").submit(SubmitForm);
});
```

And in my submit function i can do my own form data handling:

```
function SubmitForm(e) 
{
    // Suppress normal event behaviour
    e.preventDefault();

    // Validate the form
    var valid = $("#my-form").validate();
    if (valid.errorList.length > 0)
        return;

    // Collect up form data manually
    var formData =  ...(code removed for clarity)

    // Display animated gif
    $("#ajax-loader").css("display", "inline")

    // Post Form
    $.post(
            '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")',   // url
            formData,                                   // data
            SuccessFunction                             // success
        )
        .error(ErrorFunction);                         // error
}
```

Okay the scene is now set.

**Problem**

One problem is that I'm mixing two types of ajax. This leads to double posts. Using fiddler I can see the post is happening twice. (Once for the micosoft form declaration and one for the jquery post)
It's because 2 handlers have been hooked up. Doing a bit of googling i found some people are removing one handler using jquery but it all looked a bit messy.

**STEP 3**

So I changed the @using (Ajax.BeginForm( ... syntax into a simple form tag:

```
<form id = "my-form">
   ...
</form>
```

**Problem**

Now the @Html.ValidationMessageFor is not doing its stuff. Using firebug i can see that my form inputs no longer have validation attributes applied.

@Html.ValidationMessageFor seems to only work in conjunction with a form helper.

I can't use Ajax.BeginForm(... because i get double submissions.

**STEP 4**

So i next used:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "my-form" })) 
 {....
```

I'm using the Html.BeginForm purely to make my @Html.ValidationMessageFor do their stuff. The "MyAction" and "MyController" parameters are all redundant because my custom event handler takes over the form submission process.

**Resolved**

Everything seems to now work

1. No double submissions
2. Unobtrusive validation using  @Html.ValidationMessageFor
3. Customised form handling / submission
4. Client and server side validation

**My question.**

Is this the right approach? 
I'd be interested to hear anyone elses experiences along these lines.

Regards

Phil

Answer (score 0):

Normally in this type of scenario I like the approach suggested in [Fluent Validation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation). Now, first thing It will generate validation for you on client that can be check with JQuery and also you can create / generate force validation on server end. Means you define rule in class as shown in example and then check for validation using that class. So, it will check on server end. I normally use ajax just not to write html, most of the time I ll forget closing bracket and few things so helpers are good but I am not in support of Ajax.Beginform. Simple Beginform is good.

I normally go with the thumb rule, that view must have simple and clear HTML or Helpers, I tried to have less nested div and other stuff.

Please let me know if any further details needed over this topic. There few good articles you can found about this over web. If you want I can share.